# Get event log error message from CloudWatch to Lambda and send it to MS Teams Webhook

Tags: tomcat, aws-lambda, microsoft-teams, error-logging, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using the CloudWatch agent to catch tomcat logs, which are all errors. The agent publishes the log streams to a log group, and what I want is to get these log errors and send them to an MS Teams channel using anything like SNS, Lambda, ...

My only issue is that I could do all of the above except for that I can't get the error message, for example:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet...
```

I am using the following python code to get this done, which I picked from AWS documentation.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import urllib3 
import json

http = urllib3.PoolManager() 

url = "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/xxxxxxxxx"
msg = {
    "text": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
}
encoded_msg = json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')
resp = http.request('POST', url, body = encoded_msg)
print({
    # "message": event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'], 
    "message": " ** Payload ** " ,
    "status_code": resp.status, 
    "response": resp.data
})
```

Comment: We might if you showed us some of the code that produces the error :-)

Comment: @Maurice it doesn't matter, any java exception, because the area I am working on is between the event logs and Lambda, but I'll specify the lambda code..

Comment: @Khadjiev, Could you please a have look on this document related to [incoming webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook) and could you please specify which document you have referred to ?

Comment: Hi @Khadjiev, Are you facing this issue? If yes, could you please confirm on how are the logs are being sent via webhook as incoming webhook only supports adaptive cards or message cards to be posted.

Comment: Hi @Khadjiev, Just to confirm sending message using cURL is working for you? If not, could you please check the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#post-a-message-to-the-webhook-using-curl).

Comment: @Mallipriya-MSFT It's working.

Answer (score -1):

cURL syntax and basic understanding about it, please follow below steps.

1. From the command line, enter the following cURL command:

   // on macOS or Linux
   curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": "Hello World"}'

   // on Windows
   curl.exe -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{'text':'Hello World'}"
2. If the POST succeeds, you should see a simple 1 output by curl.
3. Check the Microsoft Team client. You should see the new card posted to the team.